# Node serverside rendering by parsing static bundle files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I am looking into server side rendering for a `react`/`webpack` web application. Then I was wondering.. Is it any simple way of processing the static files produced by webpack? So the server side renderer read the index.html file that contains the bundle, run the javascript in it so the react app is injected into the html, and then return the result...

Something like:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**entry.js** (the webpack entry for building bundle.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Application from 'src/Application';

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Application)
);
```

**Application.jsx**

```
export default function() {
    return (
        <div>Hello World!</div>
    );
}
```

Then after reading and processing index.html, the result that can be sent to the client should be something like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <div>Hello World!</div>
        </div>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

***Circumstances***

Tutorials on SSR either try to server-render the react code to html, or run webpack and then read the bundle file to run the bundle code to inject the result html into an index template.

Running ReactDOMServer.renderAsString does not work with my current source because they import non-js files (like component css files) that is catched by webpack loaders. I know I can move the css imports to a separate file, but I was hoping to keep the source as is.

Comment: If you find something that does this it will be a tricky piece of engineering. That's because you basically need something that runs bundled javascript in a browser environment and returns the rendered output. I imagine some kind of collaboration between jsdom and webpack.